Is Maven Archetype Quicktstart still up to date?
I am using the Maven Archetype maven-archetype-quickstart as a boilerplate for my Java projects. It works perfectly fine, but I wonder if this is still up to date and if there are better ways to do the same. The version of the maven-archetype-quickstart is a bit outdated with version 1.4 being from Dec 13, 2018. Is there a newer way to do things? Maybe another archetype for Maven? What is the current standard?
For my projects I currently use this command for a Maven setup:
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DgroupId=com.example \
    -DartifactId=example-app \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 \
    -DinteractiveMode=false

What I then change in the pom.xml file are the Maven compiler versions from 1.7 to 17:
<properties>
  ...
  <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

Then I update the JUnit version from  to 4.13.2:
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

And then I add the Maven Shade Plugin for creating a Fat JAR:
  
    
      
        org.apache.maven.plugins
        maven-shade-plugin
        3.5.1
        
          
            package
            
              shade
            
            
              
                
                  com.example.App
                
              
            
          
        
      
    
  
The JDK version I currently use is Amazon Coretto 22.

You can try
mvn archetype:generate \
 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-simple \
 -DarchetypeVersion=1.4

Not much better, but it uses Java 17.
PS: Noting stops you from creating your own archetype. It isn't that difficult.

No, not up-to-date
The latest version of Maven Quickstart Archetype is 1.4. That version was last updated in 2018.
All of the parts referenced by this archetype have moved on to later versions. But you can still use this archetype, after updating its elements. You can then write apps for the latest Java, currently Java 22.
I have no idea why this extremely useful archetype is never updated. So ironic that Maven’s original reason for being is to make such updates very easy.
Update easily
Use a search engine to find a Maven repository with that offering. For example, MvnRepository.com.
Start with that, then quickly update to the latest versions of the various parts — before versions 4. I have found all of the latest features, before 4, to be compatible with one another.
Original:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Quickie</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Quickie</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>

Your To-Do list for Maven 3:

Replacing maven.compiler.source & maven.compiler.target pair of elements with a single maven.compiler.release element.
Replacing JUnit 4 with JUnit 5 Jupiter via the Aggregator module.
Updating to the latest versions before versions 4. Versions 4 of some of these require Maven 4 which is not yet released.
Changing the AppTest.java file to replace the import statements.

Those import statements should be:
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

Your POM for Maven 3 should look something like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Quickie</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Quickie</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>22</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.0-M2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.13.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>

After all that, make Maven reload all the newly specified versions. Then do a Maven clean and install. You should then be able to run the App#main method to see your app execute successfully.

I've never quite understood why Maven doesn't any longer allow something like ${maven.latest} for its versioning

@g00se Agreed. The original point to Maven was to relieve us of manually looking up versions of dependency files within our projects. Now we manually look up versions within our POMs.

It's tempting to go ahead and write a "put the latest version of everything in my pom" oneself. I expect that wouldn't be trivial ;)

@g00se Have a look at https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html

@JFabianMeier thanks for that. Does it work on itself? ;)

@g00se I cannot quite follow you. You mean, updating the plugin versions? It can do that as well.

No sorry, I was half joking. Just that versions-maven-plugin is a plugin itself right..?

For my students, I created the java21-quickstart and javafx-quickstart archetypes using Java 21, Junit 5, Log4j2, Lombok, and a second one JavaFX. So getting started with Java is a little bit easier. Both archetypes are published in https://mvnrepository.com
